# What is the best index to create for such a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with documents like this:

```json
{
  "_id":{
    "$oid":"60c5316cbc885e00c6e5abeb"
  },
  "name":"<name>",
  "addedAt":{
    "date":{
      "$date":"2021-06-12T22:13:00.316Z"
    },
    "timestamp":1623535980.316648
  },
  "lastUsed":{
    "date":{
      "$date":"2021-06-22T14:17:23.339Z"
    },
    "timestamp":1624371443.339323
  },
  "connStr":"http://<user>:<pwd>@<host>:<port>",
  "resetIpUri":"http://<host>:<port>/api/changeIP?apiToken=<token>",
  "lastResetIP":1623535980.316648
}
```

And pretty simple queries:

```
db.collection.find({connStr: <connStr>})
db.collection.find({}).sort({"lastUsed.timestamp": 1})
```

But I'm not quite sure if I need to use a text index for the field `conStr`, or a regular one? I cannot understand how text indexes work, do I always need to use them when I have a task to find a document by its value, if so, should I use text indexes for integer or float fields?

Comment: You can use normal ascending or descending order type index instead of test index and it should work just fine if you are going to do a normal match and sort operation. `db.collection.createIndex({connStr: 1})`. Let me know if you have further queries.

Comment: @hhharsha36 but what about text indexes? when should i really use them? For example, in my document I have the value "A2131BBVYFTL212" if this field is a text index, will full-text search work faster or not?

Comment: I have added an answer since there is a word count for comments. Hope it helped you out.

Comment: Do you store passwords as clear text in your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text Indexes and regular Indexes are entirely different and should be used under entirely different scenarios.

**Go for Normal Indexing if:**

You will be matching the exact string value of a key or you will be using `Regex` operations on the string value stored.

> The Normal Index is what you are looking for.

**Go for Text Indexing if:**

You want the values of a key to be stemmed for searching purposes. For Example The stemming of the root word `like` are: `likes`, `liked`, `likely`, `liking`, etc. All these are stems of the root word `like`.

If you want a key value to be searchable, like textbook name or description, you can make use of the `text` indexing, and perform a text search on the key, which will perform a stem search of all the words.

> Note: I am no MongoDB Text Index expert and just have a vague idea of what it is. Any corrections and edits are welcomed.

Comment: So I understand correctly that if I have a document with the value ```A2131BBVYFTL212``` and I want to find it by the full value of the field, and not by part, then I do not need a text index? Do I need a text index when I need to search by part of a value?

Comment: You do not require the Text index even if you want to search part of the string (using something like regex). The normal index will work just fine. Example: If you want to search for the value `A2131BBVYFTL212` by `A2131BBV`, `db.col.find({/A2131BBV/})` will use index scan if applied. Only use text index if you are building for example an e-commerce site and the search query will be performed based on user inputs, which will have uncertainty, spelling mistakes, and match alternative stems of a text like `simple` `simply` etc.  What you are looking for will work fine on the normal index.

Comment: Let me know if you have further doubts. I know it's confusing because of the term text in the index type.